# What spell permits the caster to take on the alignment of a nearby person or object?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, alignment

A **Good** character wants to infiltrate the headquarters of an **Evil** organization using a disguise. Said organization will cast Detect Good on all newcomers once upon entry. The character wants to pass that exam because Strategy (not avoid it).

[Undetectable Alignment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undetectable-alignment/) will raise eyebrows at the entry gate. "Everyone else submits to the scan. What have you got to hide, newcomer?"
[Nondetection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/nondetection/) will raise alarm bells for the same reason. Perhaps he could bluff his way past, but the objective here is to satisfy the test and get accepted by the gatekeepers.

I thought there was a Pathfinder spell which allowed the caster to pick something in close range, like nearby Chaotic Evil NPC Who Just Kicked A Puppy, and register as the alignment of that NPC: CE. Or you carry an unholy LE object in your backpack; under the spell, you register as Lawful Evil. Or you could pick up a pebble, cast the spell with the target as the pebble, and register as Neutral.

I have not found that in my Pathfinder 1e books so far.

---

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You're probably looking for the spell [Misdirection](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Misdirection)**

> By means of this spell, you misdirect the information from divination spells that reveal auras (detect evil, detect magic, discern lies, and the like). On casting the spell, you choose another object within range. For the duration of the spell, the subject of misdirection is detected as if it were the other object. Neither the subject nor the other object gets a saving throw against this effect. Detection spells provide information based on the second object rather than on the actual target of the detection unless the caster of the detection succeeds on a Will save.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was thinking of, and could not find. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As [previously mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178431/14848), the spell you were looking for is *misdirection*.  However, the correct spell for the situation is actually [infernal healing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/infernal-healing/).  While the latter can only imitate evil, it allows no save.

---

Comment: That is a good find. I had not heard of that one. Nice.

Comment: it's a pity that  it only lasts for a minute, but maybe it can be got as a potion.

Answer (score 4):

As long as they're only casting *detect good*, both of the spells you mentioned in your question work just fine.  Someone under the effects of *nondetection* or *undetectable alignment* will appear identical to any other non-good creature to *detect good* (*nondetection*, however, does allow a caster level check to penetrate it).

If they're supplementing *detect good* with *detect evil*, however, the character will simply appear neutral, which might not be good enough.  If they're also casting *detect magic*, *undetectable alignment* will show up loud and clear, although the detector will still need to pass a CL check to notice *nondetection*.